# Unreal Engine - Can I use animations for the Mannequin Hand Skeletal Mesh, in the Full Mannequin Body’s hands?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I'm working in a VR project, and until recently I only had Skeletal Meshes of hands with animations. But recently I found a plugin for an upper body IK (it's called UBIK https://github.com/JonasMolgaard/UBIKSolver) animation based on the position of the Headset and the hands.

And I don't know how to implement those animations made for hand skeletons, to a full body skeletal mesh.

I don't even know if it's possible. If it isn't then I'll create every animation one by one, for each hand, but using the full body skeleton, and then do a montage or blend? That way I can move my body but also see the animations in the hands?

I'm honestly figuring this out as I go, so any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can blend animations as long as they're for the same Skeletal Mesh. [Here's](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/AnimatingObjects/SkeletalMeshAnimation/AnimationBlending/) Unreal's own documentation for it. If the animations you've made already are for another Skeletal Mesh, which will most likely be the case, give [Retargeting](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/AnimatingObjects/SkeletalMeshAnimation/AnimationRetargeting/) a go.